# How can I code a graph visibility criterion using an If-statement?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The visibility criterion can be defined as follows: two arbitrary data values $(ta , ya)$ and $(tb , yb)$ are visible to each other if any other data $(tc, yc)$ placed between them fulfills the following constraint:

$\qquad yc < (yb + ((ya - yb)((tb-tc)/(tb-ta))))$

The list is

```
timemagnitude = 
  {{13.801, 1.03}, {35.6257, 1.67}, {138.025, 2.21}, {149.743, 1.65}, {254.24, 2.29}, 
   {257.262, 1.77}, {366.407, 1.49}, {369.419, 1.5}, {438.116, 2.28}, {522.69, 1.98}, 
   {529.661, 1.43}, {576.86, 1.76}, {584.129, 1.16}, {592.416, 1.74}, {614.998, 1.71}}
```

How is it possible to implement my criterion using `If`?

I have use this but not work with criterion. Because this code work with list

```
l = {{1.03, 1.67, 2.21, 1.65, 2.29, 1.77, 1.49, 1.5, 2.28, 1.98}}

fiedif[m_, n_, data_] := 
  If[(Min[#[[m]], #[[n]]] > Max[#[[m + 1 ;; n - 1]]])& @ data, 
  m \[DirectedEdge] n]

edgesSd[l_] := 
  edgesSd[l] = 
    Cases[
      Flatten[Table[fiedif[m, n, #], {m, Length[#]}, {n, m + 1, Length[#]}]], 
      _ \[DirectedEdge] _] & /@ l
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but perhaps you can reply with clarifications to this answer. You have a boolean function, let's call it `visible` which returns `True` or `False` depending on the input of three 2D points:

```
visible[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{ya, yb, yc, ta, tb, tc},
 {ta, ya} = a;
 {tb, yb} = b;
 {tc, yc} = c;
 yc < (yb + ((ya - yb) ((tb - tc)/(tb - ta))))
]
```

To visualize this, you can write a simple `Manipulate` which shows that `visible` is going to be either `True` or `False` depending on what side of the line through `a` and `b` it lies:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   {Black, AbsoluteThickness[3], InfiniteLine[{a, b}]},
   {Green, Opacity[.5], 
    HalfPlane[{a, b}, RotationTransform[\[Pi]/2][a - b]]},
   {Red, Opacity[.5], 
    HalfPlane[{a, b}, RotationTransform[\[Pi]/2][b - a]]},
   Text["a", a + .2],
   Text["b", b + .2],
   Text["c", c + .2]
   },
  PlotRange -> 4, Axes -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[visible[a, b, c], 24, Bold]
  ],
 {{a, {-1, 2}}, Locator},
 {{b, {2, -3}}, Locator},
 {{c, {3, 3}}, Locator}]
```

For example, here `c` lies on the side where `visible` returns `False`:

[image]

And here is an example where `c` lies on the side where `visible` returns `True`:

[image]

So then you should be able to use this boolean `visible` function directly in any `If` statement, like so:

```
If[ 
 visible[a,b,c]
 , 
 (* do something for c being visible *)
 ,
 (* do something for c being invisible *)
 ]
```

(But I feel like I don't fully understand your question and code, so maybe you can clarify a bit more?)

Comment: Thanks for help, Arnoud Buzing.